# What is the usual way to reformat paragraph in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

When you have a text file with long lines, what is the way to reformat them to a certain width, while
not jumbling them up together?

Generally, what I'm looking for is this in Vim,
(to be done on every line)

```
V
gq
j
```

with `textwidth` set in advance.

Comment: Looks like vim still has an edge on Sublime in some ways.

Comment: @Jondlm - I would say in many (or maybe I don't know how to do some operations in ST2). But ST2 is really a nice editor, can't deny it - find myself using it more and more, only occasionally switching to Vim when I need to do something and don't have time to figure out how. They make a nice pair.

Comment: @Idigas - Agreed! I also use the two in tandem. Did you see my answer below about vintage mode?

Comment: @Jondlm - Yes, of course, and I'll accept it if no one comes up with a better approach. I'm hoping for some python custom solution or something because going into Preferences and changing the option to enable vintage mode, than going back, doing an operation on text, and back again really doesn't sound like a "smooth flow". It's not that yours isn't a good approach, but when using vintage mode I think, why do I use ST in the first place. I might as well switch back to vim.

Comment: @Idigas Fair play. Though I find vintage mode to be really useful when combined with Sublime only concepts such as multiple cursors.

Comment: @Idigas Check out Vintageous! http://guillermooo.bitbucket.org/Vintageous/

Answer (score 23):

`ALT` + `CMD` + `q` on OS X will hard wrap a line to whatever ruler column you have set. See [Andrew's answer for the ruler settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17159320/456814).

`ALT` + `q` works on Windows, and according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466430/what-is-the-usual-way-to-reformat-paragraph-in-sublime-text-2/22496963#comment33034809_17159320), it works on Linux too.

#### Wrapping comment lines

According to the comments, Sublime Text doesn't wrap comments very well, such as

```java
/*
 * Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 */

// Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

The plugin [Sublime Wrap Plus](https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus) can be used to wrap these. However, it doesn't seem to work well if you Select All your file, it seems to work best if you select only the comment lines that you want to wrap. (Tested in Sublime Text 3, not 2).

Comment: Does not understand comments. :(

Comment: In Vim, gq understands comments, so if you use it then it will update any prefix `*` and `//` accordingly for each line.

Answer (score 10):

The Edit → Wrap menu has a ton of options for hard wrapping paragraphs at different line lengths.

"Wrap Paragraph at Ruler" will use whatever setting you have for rulers, set like so in your user preferences (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11319526/120898):

```
// Adds a single vertical ruler at line 80
"rulers": [80],
```

Or you can set a temporary ruler with View → Ruler.

Comment: alt+Q on linux, will format the current paragraph, sort like `gwap` in vim.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is possible once you enable `vintage` mode:

1. `Preferences > Settings -- Default`
2. Remove `Vintage` from the `ignored_packages` section

Vintage mode makes Sublime act like VIM, for the most part. Now you can use the key combo you mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

Sublime will reindent code for you and usually does a pretty good job. You can find the option in the menu if you go to Edit → Line → Reindent.

Or You can have a custom key binding setup in Sublime so You can reindent code with shortcut.
To do that, just add the following line to Preferences → Key Bindings – User.

```
{"keys": ["alt+shift+r"], "command": "reindent" , "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP wants paragraph *reflow*. I'm also looking to do the same in ST2. The Wrap Plus plugin introduces wrapping that is a bit fancier than the default but that's not the same as reflowing.