# sublime text : how to fill paragraph?

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

In emacs, you can use `meta-q` "fill-paragraph" and in vim you can do `gq` - reformat paragraph (`gggqG` to fill the entire buffer)

Is there a similar key binding in sublime text?

Example:

Before fill-paragraph:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
```

After fill-paragraph:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam
```

Comment: See also: [What is the usual way to reformat paragraph in Sublime Text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22496963/456814).

Answer (score 8):

***New Answer***

OK, so I misunderstood your original question - as I [now understand it](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs18/emacs_24.html#SEC141), <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>-"`fill-paragraph`" rearranges paragraphs into lines of approximately-equal lengths. There isn't a function that matches this exactly in Sublime, but you can (re)wrap lines quite easily. You can set the ruler in your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file, using the `"wrap_width"` setting. Then, using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> on Windows/Linux, or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> on OS X, you can wrap selected text to that width (it defaults to 78 characters if `"wrap_width"` is set to `0`). If you want to wrap to other (pre-selected) widths, go to `Edit -> Wrap` and there are a number of other options. To set a preferred width outside of what is in your preferences, open `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and add the following:

```json
[
    // wrap lines at 25 characters
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+w"], "command": "wrap_lines", "args": {"width": 25} }
]
```

You can obviously change the 25 to whatever value suits you. If you have no custom key bindings so far, copy and paste the entire contents above into the file. If you already have some key bindings, omit the outer square brackets, and remember to place a comma at the end of the line if it's not the final entry in the file. Good luck!

Comment: @phils - it's still not that clear (my Emacs-fu is only beginner-level). Does it just wrap the lines?