# What is the default font of Sublime Text?

Tags: fonts, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I was looking and could not find an answer on this one. Which is Sublime Text's default font type?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

On Linux it's **`Monospace`** 10 pt. (the exact monospace font used may vary on different Linux distributions or versions), on Windows it's **`Consolas`** 10 pt., and on OS X it's **`Menlo Regular`** 12 pt.

[image: default platform preferences]

<sup>*(The color scheme is [`Neon`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), the syntax highlighting is from [`PackageDev`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev), and the font is [Liberation Mono](https://github.com/liberationfonts/liberation-fonts)*</sup>

This information is found in the `Packages/Default` directory (where `Packages` is the directory opened by the **`Preferences → Browse Packages...`** menu option), in the `Preferences (OS).sublime-settings` file where ***`OS`*** is one of `Windows`, `Linux`, or `OSX`.

You should only customize the font (or any other setting) in `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`, opened by **`Preferences → Settings—User`**, as **`Settings—Default`** is over-written on upgrade, and also serves as a backup in case you really screw something up in your user settings. This is the case for both the main Sublime settings as well as those for extra packages/plugins.

These default fonts are the same in Sublime Text 2, Sublime Text 3, and the new version currently in development.

Comment: On my Ubuntu linux, it looks like the default is not Monospace. The font looks different (and better) than, say, selecting Monospace in NetBeans.

Comment: @matt as I mentioned, the exact font may vary. Also, Sublime uses a custom rendering engine, specifically designed to make fonts look better, so the same font may render differently in different programs. I'm not terribly familiar with NetBeans, but it may have an option to select exactly what font is used when `monospace` is chosen. This font may be different than Sublime's.

Comment: mmmm... I see. I guess monospace is not a real/final font but something that maps to some font somewhere..

Comment: @matt yup, you got it.

Comment: I have a quite similar question:'what is the default font of the "build result plane"? And where to set it? ' In my PC, the font is not monospaced and bother me so much.

Comment: @PaleNeutron if you have a new question please ask it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: That should be "Menlo-Regular" on OSX

Comment: @Gerry *Menlo-Regular* is the name of the font file, the font's name is *Menlo* and the style name is *Regular* (as opposed to *Italic* or *Bold* or *Narrow* or whatever).

Comment: When I click `Preferences -> Browse Packages` nothing opens or happens. In Packages directory I only have User directory. No `Preferences (OS).sublime-settings` file. Kubuntu 16.10, ST3

Comment: @HrvojeT I haven't used Kubuntu (just plain Ubuntu), so I'm not sure why that menu option isn't working. The `Default` directory actually doesn't exist physically in `Packages`, it's stored in a `.sublime-package` archive file in `Installed Packages`. If you want to examine its contents, or those of any other default package, you should use [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer).

Comment: @MattDMo I actually Like your color Theme. Can you share the name ?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 4 (Build 4126) on Linux Ubuntu 18.04. The `Packages/Default` directory (full path would be `$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User`) no longer exists. Where are these defaults stored now?

Comment: Follow-up question I just asked: [Where are the default settings, such as "font_size", stored in Sublime Text 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71261218/4561887)

Comment: Anyway, I guess the main takeaway is that for Sublime Text 3 and 4 you can just see the defaults by looking in the left-hand pane that opens up when you go to **Preferences --> Settings**.

Answer (score 68):

On my system (Windows 8.1), Sublime 2 shows default font "Consolas". You can find yours by following this procedure:

1. go to View menu and select Show Console
2. Then enter this command: `view.settings().get('font_face')`

You will find your default font.

Comment: Very nice! And with `view.settings().get('font_size')` you get the font size as well.

Answer (score 31):

Yes. You can use Console of Sublime with (Linux):

```
Ctrl + `
```

And type:

```
view.settings().get('font_face')
```

Get any setting the same way.

Comment: Or go to View -> Show Console

Answer (score 11):

To add to [MattDMo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858722/399105), you can get the exact font that's used on Linux like so (the example is from Xubuntu 14.04):

```
$ fc-match Monospace
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
```

Comment: This is correct. In Kubuntu 16.10 when I set font for 'Fixed width' as Monospace and then set it as DejaVu Sans Mono Book it looks the same in a settings sample preview. Not one pixel changes. `fc-match Monospace` returns `DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"`

Answer (score 3):

The default font on windows 10 is `Consolas`