# How to install 'Emilbus Mono' Font in sublime text 3 in windows?

Tags: windows, sublimetext3

Heard emilbus Mono is the default font in sublimetext 3 in ubuntu.  I want to install the same font on my windows sublime text installation as well. I tried searching the internet but I Couldn't find it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default font of Sublime Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857899/what-is-the-default-font-of-sublime-text)

Comment: @MattDMo Just have a look at this [link](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11438). The second reply shows a sublime text window with font installed.. Your answer to the other question tells about how to find the default font but not how to install it. Here I want to install it on my windows as well. But still thank you for your response.

Comment: Okay, Finally after too many futile attempts to find "emilbuS Mono", found an alternative for it in windows. "Inconsolata"!! Yes, almost close to emilbus but not rendered as perfectly as Emilbus in Ubuntu. And make sure "directwrite" and "no_antialias" in "font_options" are NOT set.

Comment: emilbuS... you're just looking at it wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but if someone is still looking for it. You literally just write "font_face": "Emilbus Mono" in settings and that's it. emilbuS - Sublime, it's internal Sublime font and you set it by just typing it in settings.