# Where is the default settings file, which stores thing such as "font_size", located for Sublime Text 4?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

I'm using Sublime Text 4 (Build 4126) on Linux Ubuntu 18.04. The `Packages/Default` directory (full path would be `$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User`), which this answer refers to: [What is the default font of Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858722/4561887)?, no longer exists.

Where are these defaults stored now? I can see them in the left-hand pane in **Preferences --> Settings**, but where is that file?

If you go to Preferences --> Settings in Sublime Text 4 it opens the preferences, with the defaults on the left, and it even shows the path as `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings` *even though that file doesn't actually exist on my file system (the `Default` folder in that path does not exist).*

[image]

To try to find a file ending in `sublime-settings`, and containing `"font_face":`, for instance, I ran this command, but didn't find any "defaults" type file anywhere:

```sh
# Read all paths with "sublime-settings" in their path name into a regular bash
# "indexed" array named `array`
mapfile -t array <<< "$(find / 2> /dev/null | grep -E "sublime-settings")"
# Pass this list of files to `grep` and search for `"font_size":`
grep -i '"font_size":' -- "${array[@]}"
```

Also, here is the result of `find ~/.config/ | grep -e sublime-text`:

```sh
$ find ~/.config/ | grep -e sublime-text
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/SublimeTutor.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/Default (Windows).sublime-keymap
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_4_5.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_7.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_10.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_13.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_4.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_5_4.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/code
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/code/chapter_1.rb
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/sublimetutor.sublime-project
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_1.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3_6.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_5_3.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_4_1.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_4_3.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_3.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_4_2.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3_8.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_12.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_5_2.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_8.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_1.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_15.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/contents.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_2.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3_5.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_5.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_11.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_6.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_14.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3_2.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_9.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_4.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3_4.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3_7.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3_3.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3_1.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_2_6.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_3.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_5_5.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_4_4.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/sublimetutor.sublime-workspace
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/README.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_5.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_5_1.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/tutorial/chapter_4_6.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/package-metadata.json
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/sublime_tutor.py
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/Main.sublime-menu
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/Default.sublime-commands
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/LICENSE
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/CONTRIBUTORS.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/.no-sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/messages.json
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/messages
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/messages/1.0.1.txt
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/messages/install.txt
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/README.md
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Sublime Tutor/.gitignore
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Git Config.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Build.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/MarkdownTOC.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/C++.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Markdown.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Python.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Makefile.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/SBSCompareTheme.hidden-tmTheme
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/SBSCompareScheme.hidden-color-scheme
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.user-ca-bundle
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/ANSIescape
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/ANSIescape/ansi.sublime-color-scheme
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/YAML.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Bash.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Plain text.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/XML.sublime-settings
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Github Tools.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Awk.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Case Conversion.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Git.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Tabright.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Git blame.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Devicetree DTS Highlighting.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/MarkdownTOC.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Compare Side-By-Side.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/0_package_control_loader.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/ANSIescape.sublime-package
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Log
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Local
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/License.sublime_license
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Auto Save Session.sublime_session
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Lib
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Lib/python3.3
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Lib/python33
/home/gabriel/.config/sublime-text-3/Lib/python38
```

It seems to me that `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings` file may not actually exist, and may just be a fake path Sublime Text created for historical reasons. Perhaps those defaults are actually built into the binary of Sublime Text 4 now, instead.

Anyway, I guess the main takeaway is that for Sublime Text 3 and 4 you can just see the defaults by looking in the left-hand pane that opens up when you go to **Preferences --> Settings**.

### References

1. [my own answer which I referenced for the `find` and `mapfile` cmd above] [Super User: Can't pipe in bash's "mapfile" ... but why?](https://superuser.com/a/1706858/425838)

Answer (score 0):

Quick find `find ~/.config/ | grep -e sublime-text` on my system shows

```
.config/sublime-text
.config/sublime-text/Packages
.config/sublime-text/Packages/User
.config/sublime-text/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
.config/sublime-text/Installed Packages
.config/sublime-text/Local
.config/sublime-text/Local/Session.sublime_session
.config/sublime-text/Log
.config/sublime-text/Lib
.config/sublime-text/Lib/python33
.config/sublime-text/Lib/python38
```

Run the above command and check if there is anything similar.

I have only Sublime Text 4 (Build 4126) installed. You most probably have both somehow.

Comment: I added the output from my computer to my question. I did start with Sublime Text 3 and then did an upgrade. All I have runnable is Sublime Text 4, Build 4126.

Comment: Open the preferences file you found in sublime and then update the font size from `Preferences=>Font=>(Larger || smaller)`. Verify if it is reflected in the preferences file. If it does then then 'All is well'

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it!

Open the file at `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Default.sublime-package`. If you double-click it in a GUI file manager it opens up like a zip file.

From there, open up `Preferences (Linux).sublime-settings`, and I see this:

```json
{
    "font_face": "Monospace",
    "font_size": 10,
    "move_to_limit_on_up_down": true,
    "mouse_wheel_switches_tabs": true
}
```

### Going further

Interesting, it looks like the mouse scroll wheel settings are here too as `button2`, but I haven't tried messing with them. I wonder perhaps if changing those scroll wheel settings (which do NOT exist in the left-hand pane of Preferences --> Settings) might be an alternative to using `imwheel` to change scroll speed (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/991680/327339), [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/touchpad_toggle.sh), and [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.imwheelrc#L46-L53)--search for "Sublime Text" in this last one).

From the `Scroll Bar (Linux).sublime-mousemap` file inside that default package compressed file above:

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1",
        "press_command": "scroll_drag",
    },
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["shift"],
        "press_command": "scroll_step",
        "press_args": { "follow_mouse": false, "delay": 1000, "interval": 200 },
    },
    {
        "button": "button2",
        "press_command": "scroll_adjust",
        "press_args": {
            "acceleration_dead_zone": 15,
            "acceleration_area": 200,
            "min_speed": 200,
            "max_speed": 5000,
        },
    },
    {
        "button": "button3",
        "press_command": "scroll_step",
        "press_args": { "follow_mouse": false, "delay": 1000, "interval": 200 },
    },
]
```

There is also a file named `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap`, and there are files for `...(OSX)...` and `...(Windows)...`.

Comment: **Please don't change the default settings!** They are hidden for a number of reasons. First, if you screw up something in your User Preferences, you always have the (working) defaults to go back to. Second, each time Sublime upgrades your changes will be overwritten. Third, there is simply no need to - you can override *every single default* by putting a different value in your user settings.

Comment: @MattDMo, I don't see a single one of the entries from the `Scroll Bar (Linux).sublime-mousemap` in my code block above in the default settings in the left-hand pane when you open Preferences --> Settings. No, not one. That implies they cannot be overridden I would think...unless you change that default file. (I haven't tested this theory on those settings).

Comment: They can be, you just need to create a file called `Scroll Bar (Linux).sublime-settings` in your `Packages/User` directory and add the settings you want to override. There are settings (like these) that aren't in the main `Preferences[ (OS)].sublime-settings` files, but they can still be modified by the user without editing the defaults.