# Show Sublime Text Columns

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Lines numbers are shown by default at the left of the screen in Sublime Text. Is there a way to get column numbers to show at the top of the screen?

Comment: If a ruler is enough for you can follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910143/how-to-make-ruler-always-be-shown-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: Not what i was looking for, but it'll do for now.

ty